# Call binary from React Native?

Tags: javascript, go, react-native

Is it possible to include and exec a compiled binary inside a React Native project? I'm exploring handling the business logic in React Native with languages other than Javascript, but still have the compiled code be cross platform.

Comment: umm, no.  unless you can use C bindings and expose them from the binary to consume.  even then you are looking at consuming a library, not a binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can [access native modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content), so uncompiled source code in either Java or Objective-c / Swift is possible. Compiled binaries are always compiled for one platform, which means that you can not link such binaries in to react native. For moving the logic away from Javascript, you have two options

1. Connect a web server and store most of the business logic there, so use the iOS / Android app mostly as a view layer.
2. Find a transpiler, that transpiles the language you would like to use to Javascript